# Intercept browser requests and modification of the server response

Tags: .net, http, response, intercept, sniffer

I want to intercept all browser requests and then add some js into server responses before it will appears in browser.

For example "Ad muncher" is doing it. It add js that removes all ad from pages.

Please give me some advise, how I can do it?

I'm using C#.

I found 2 solutions that may be can help me:

1) **www.fiddler2.com** 
But as I understand I could only write my own plugin for it, but I can't make standalone application. And also it is a proxy-type solution..

2) **www.tcpdump.org** and **www.winpcap.org**
I can't find how to modify server responses, I found some info only about sniffering the requests.

***P.S: I don't want to use proxy server for this purpose.***

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Why don't you want to use a proxy server? Fiddle is a proxy, so why don't you want to write your own?

Comment: Because I want the cross-browser solution, I don't want to let user change any browser settings. Also user could work througth some other proxy... I didn't know that fiddler is a proxy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you thought about writing plugin for the browser? It won't be a generic solution, because you'll have to develop plugin for each popular browser - but it'll do the work and i think it'll be much simpler than other solutions..

Anyway, winpcap doesn't allow you to modify packets.
You can check another options, such as WFP (Windows Filtering Platform - available from windows vista) and implement this with them - but it might be a bit overkill and i don't think you can use .NET for this. you can read about this here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb757027.aspx